# How to do login with Spring MVC & Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I am creating a simple login & registration project with spring mvc & hibernate but not known how to read data from data base with hibernate & mySQL for login process only, could anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication in Spring Boot is a big topic on its own, but there exists really good tutorials on the internet for it. In general, [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com) has some of the best tutorials on Spring Boot (and other Java stuff), in my opinion. There is a whole collection of articles about security, including login and registration.

Take a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring